# Redis. Php Cache + Php Session

Tags: php, session, caching, redis

I use Redis for storing session and storing cache, and I want to implement "Clear cache" feature.

I have got a number of problems:

1) Redis cannot delete by pattern ("ENTITY_CACHE:*")

2) "flushall" deletes both Cache and Sessions (Session should not be deleted)

3) Multiple DB feature is deprecated, so I may not use "flashdb"

4) Get all keys by pattern ("ENTITY_CACHE:*") and then, delete each key - as for me this is bad practice, count of these keys may be over a million...

`$redis->delete($redis->keys('ENTITY_CACHE:*'))`

The only solution I prefer is:
Use multiple instances of Redis, separated instance for Session and for Cache. But I am not sure if this is a good solution

Can you give me some advice?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you caching a million of in redis?

Comment: In general, cache means huge amount of entries, and I use ZF2 Cache Storage and it does not give access to RedisClient instance, it is protected property

Answer (score 0):

> But I am not sure if this is a good solution

I feel it is. I separate Session and Cache on separate instances as it allows me to specify different memory limits (maxmemory) for each and eviction is more controllable (it uses the LRU algorithm). Also the persistence settings are seeming to be instance wide. Note that session storage without session locking should be avoided. I strongly advice to use [SncRedisBundle](https://github.com/snc/SncRedisBundle) as it implements locking (and PHP's Redis extension does not).

Does that help?

Comment: This is the answer for sure. Cache and dB need to be treated differently to do that needs separate instance